I have a 9V DC motor. Does it always consume the same amount of power?
Let's say I have an Arduino + motor shield connected to a 9V motor. At rest it consumes X watts. Now when I activate and spin the motor it consumes Y watts. Is X=Y?

X = 0 .........

By "at rest", do you mean "turned off" (like @jsotola comment), or "turned on" with the rotor stalled (not rotating)?     With the rotor locked and constant voltage supply applied, a DC motor draws the maximum current (due to no reverse EMF) and consumes the maximum power, and acts like a pushy heater.

@BK303 yes I mean "turned on" and not rotating. I am thinking of this in the context of microcontrollers. An Arduino cam send control signals to actuate a motor, or it can leave the motor at rest. In both cases the motor is "powered". But is it equal?

Why do you say a that when the controller is "leaving the motor at rest" that "the motor is powered"?  Any simple DC or AC motor is only at rest when it is NOT powered, or when something is locking it preventing rotation while power is applied. When you apply power, the motor immediately tries to rotate.  Are you using a servo? which is actually a mini position controller with feedback, a position sensor, and a motor.  In a servo, there is always power applied to operate it's control loop and sensor.

Assuming a DC brushed motor.
If the motor has no voltage on it and is not turning, then the power consumption of the motor is zero.
If the motor has voltage on it then the power consumption depends on how fast it is turning, which, in turn depends on the load. If the motor is stalled, the motor consumption is generally very high and the motor may overheat.
When voltage is first applied, because of rotor and load inertia, the motor behaves as if it is stalled- power consumption is high and then may drop back as the motor spins up (depending on the load friction and so on).
If the motor is driven mechanically, the power consumption can be negative- it can present a voltage to the driving circuitry, which is not always good.
If the motor is turning in one direction and voltage is applied to drive it in the opposite, then the current will be higher than the stall current, possibly enough to damage the motor.

You may confusing Ohm's Law with the Law of Conservation of Energy. If P = IV where I is 0A from the motor being idle (ideally) or 0.3A from the motor turning, and V is always 9V (again, ideally), so the wattage is different...
Now with energy, you have U1 = U2, where U is the total amount of energy in systems 1 and 2. So in this case, the energy from the 9V battery will always equal to the energy in the motor. Whether that motor has kinetic energy, thermal energy, etc., it will add up to the same amount of energy in the 9V battery.
